# Smart target promotions not visible on Fredhopper even after performing required config change

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I'm using Smart target 2014SP1 and FAS 7.5.1.3. I would like to make the smart target promotions visible on Fredhopper side to troubleshoot an issue, to do that i have followed this [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-287608E8-1E7A-4BE5-9682-B84B8FB4B8E4). However, i couldnt see the smart target promotions on the Fredhopper "Business Manager=>Targetting=> Manage campaigns" tab. But i could see those promotions on Fredhopper preview by applying the triggers. I have restarted the indexer and qserver after performing the config change. I'm wondering why still smart target promotions are not visible in Business Manager? Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you created the file in the right folder and named it correctly? Also, if you are on Windows, check if your Explorer is hiding a rogue '.txt' file extension or similar.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Issue was with .txt extension which was hidden by windows explorer!!

Comment: Great that it's solved. I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double-check that you have created the file in the right folder and named it correctly. If you are on Windows, check if your Explorer is hiding a '.txt' file extension. This can happen if you create a new text file and have file extensions hidden (View | File name extensions).